# vertical-align: middle on td in IE8 (ok in IE7/FF/Chrome)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, vertical-alignment

I have a simple fixed width table. The first column has a fluid width and contains some simple text. The other columns are fixed width, and contain a padded div with some more simple text in them. All elements of the table are set to vertical-align: middle. Everything vertically aligns fine in IE7+, FF, Chrome, etc.

Then I've added some JS to toggle the display of the fixed width columns. Everything remains vertically aligned in FF, Chrome, even IE7, but for some reason IE8 goes screwy.

Here's an demo: http://www.pinksy.co.uk/table.html

To demonstrate:

1. Toggle column 4. Column 5 will then be vertically aligned as if it was still the old row height.
2. Toggle column 3. Column 4 and 5 will then be vertically aligned as if it was still the old row height.
3. Toggle column 2. Column 3, 4, and 5 will then be vertically aligned as if it was still the old row height.

So, it's something to do with IE8 not being able to recalculate the vertical alignment of the remaining right-most columns with respect to the new row height.

The crazy thing is, it's fine in IE7! Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: IE8. The brain in the KFC of the browser world. It's curious that it _does_ work in IE7 but not IE8. Perhaps try changing your doctype to Strict, or just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: Nice thought, but that didn't work either, sadly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My IE8 was running on Compatibility View mode. I could replicate your issue when I switched to normal mode. I added a nested table for the numbers and that fixed it...

```
<td class="title">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a pharetra risus. Quisque sodales libero eget diam tincidunt interdum sollicitudin nunc porttitor. Donec bibendum ultrices purus sit amet viverra. Sed in libero quis tellus vehicula mattis sit amet vitae turpis.
</td>
<td>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="num1">
            <div class="val">Num1</div>
        </td>
        <td class="num2">
            <div class="val">Num2</div>
        </td>
        <td class="num3">
            <div class="val">Num3</div>
        </td>
        <td class="num4">
            <div class="val">Num4</div>
        </td>
        <td class="num5">
            <div class="val">Num5</div>
        </td>                           
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Done, see http://www.pinksy.co.uk/table2.html, but IE8 still has the same problem

Comment: Hmm...I ran it locally on apache server on IE8 and it works fine. You can try the following... 1) Change the width for the .num elements to 10% instead of 40px. 2) Not sure if you want to do this but you can set a width to **.title** CSS element. I've tried both options and they work fine.

Comment: @pinksy My IE8 was running on Compatibility View mode. Please see edited response.

Comment: Woo! It works! Yeah, sorry, I should have mentioned that it also works in IE8 Compatibility Mode. That's awesome anyway, cunning too! Thanks a lot @neo108